# How to get scrolling text and video in Adobe Premiere

Tags: adobe-premiere

I'm working with Adobe Premiere and would like to have scrolling text for credits and would like to have a stationary box beside the scrolling credit that shows some video footage.

Is it possible to do this with Premiere? I'm fine with stand alone scrolling text and obviously video :), but not having any luck combining the two.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible strictly with Premiere.  It is a straightforward two layer composition.  One video layer has the scrolling text using the text control.  Another video layer has the video footage, perhaps reduced with the zoom control.